# Cobalt 23 in OpenGL-less platform (reviving Blitter API?)

Tags: cobalt

We are running Cobalt on a MIPS based platform with no OpenGL support. We have Cobalt from **20.lts.x** and it runs perfectly. Now I m experimenting with **Cobalt 23** version and I see that OpenGL is the only way to make graphics (we were using Blitter API with 20 version which was removed).

- How difficult will it be to port-back blitter API?
- As Cobalt is just perfect for constrained systems (embedded systems), what will be your advice for platforms lacking OpenGL support?

Comment: Is Glimp a level where we can add an implementation. We are not expecting any funcy operations, only 2D operations (Many Blit and Fill)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a software based OpenGL ES renderer, such as LLVMpipe or OpenSWR. Of course, the rendering performance will likely not be great.